# IE css button outside border

Tags: html, internet-explorer, button, css

My button works in all other browsers except IE. I thought the 'border-radius' was suppose to work for IE?

[image: Screenshot of button that isn't styled correctly]

```css
.simpleHelp {
  border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
  background: #910330;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#790228), 
  to(#910330));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #790228, #910330);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #790228, #910330);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #790228, #910330);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #790228, #910330);
  padding: 10.5px 21px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
  -moz-border-radius: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
  box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
  text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.4) 0 1px 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Georgia, Serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
 }
```

Comment: You should use the unprefixed version of `linear-gradient()` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Border-radius (and, in fact, any CSS3) only works on IE9+](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius), however, you can "retrofit" CSS3 stuff onto older versions of IE9 with a fun little library called [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/). If you *really* need borders and shadows in IE, then CSS3PIE is the way to go. However, letting older browsers gracefully degrade is okay to do, too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that border-radius only works in IE9 and up.

http://www.findmebyip.com/litmus/